# Get date from the three and a half months ago

Tags: php, date, date-math

I know I can do

```
$threemonthsago = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-3 month"));
echo "$threemonthsago";
```

However I want to get 3.5 months ago not three months ago. So I tried to do

```
$threemonthsago = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-3.5 month"));
echo "$threemonthsago";
```

However it does not seem to give me the correct date its giving me like September something which it should not be since its currently April.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echo(strtotime("-105 days"));

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

The decimal throws off `strtotime()` as that is not a valid format it recognizes. The real issue you have is what exactly is half of a month? If you traverse February it gets really dicey.

This is somewhat easier to do using `DateTime()` and `DateInterval()` if you specify exactly what half of a month is:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$new_date = $date->sub(new DateInterval('P3M15D'));
echo $new_date->format('Y-m-d');
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DqshU4)

Comment: Another non-ticker eh? *hm...*

Comment: @Fred-ii- They've chosen answers before. We'll give them the benefit of the doubt that they'll be back.

Comment: They always come back ;-) Mmuuaaahh ha ha ha ha!!

Comment: @Jayreis You thanked, but did not accept this the an answer. If it did answer your question, then marking it so will help others in future.